# Should I create a new variable or always access the data from a class object?

Tags: java, performance, class, pojo, member-variables

Let's begin with an example (just for the sake of explanation)

```
public void mySecretOperation() {
    User user = new User();

    if (user.getAge() > 2 && user.getAge() < 5) {
        //TODO : do something...
    }

    if (user.getAge() > 12 && user.getAge() < 15) {
        //TODO : do something...
    }

    if (user.getAge() > 31 && user.getAge() < 55) {
        //TODO : do something...
    }

    if (user.getAge() > 78 && user.getAge() < 89) {
        //TODO : do something...
    }

}
```

Another alternative is `int age = user.getAge();` and then use `age` everywhere instead of `user.getAge()`.

- So, performance wise (or let's consider space complexity) will there
  be any difference?
- Can we say that one approach is better than other?

I know its a noob question, still curious to know.

Comment: I’d imagine it makes no difference performance wise.

Comment: int age is a variable, user.getAge() is a constant. If you look at it from that perspective you can see when to use each construct. If you don't need a variable, use the constant to eliminate the chance for error. Another consideration is performance: does it take a long time to execute user.getAge()? Probably not, but always keep that in the back of your mind.

Comment: @notyou well, let us assume that I have to do same stuff with 100s of member variables. Isn't it like creating them will take additional space in comparison to directly accessing them using object?

Comment: @nicomp user.getAge() is not a constant. i assume it's s getter function for a attribute of the instance, so i guess it could change. in fact if the user object would be change by another thread (if access is shared by multiple threads) person.getAge() could get different results for different calls here.

Comment: It is a constant. Try using it on the left side of an assignment statement.

Comment: Definitely assign it to a variable, for all we know getAge() might do some hefty calculations or in this contrived example connect to a webservice or whatever takes a lot of time...

Comment: @nicomp how do you mean it? it's not a variable it's a function call. how should i use it on the left side of an assignment? so constant is even the wrong kind of category here. and it is missleading because the value can change on each call.

Comment: @snap Did you try to use it on the left side of an expression? If you did you would learn that it cannot be assigned a new value, making it a constant. Certainly the value it returns may change when you call it a second time, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @nicomp are you talking about the function or the function call?

Comment: @snap I am talking about the expression, user.getAge(), used in the code. It's a function call.

Comment: @nicomp why should a assignment to a function call make any sense? what should it even mean? so, for me this has nothing to do with constants after all.

Comment: @snap An assignment to a function call does not make sense because a function call represents a constant expression. That's the point.

Comment: @nicomp you can never assign something to an expression, only to variables. so constant is not a meaningfull type for an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it make a difference performance wise, that's almost negligible. So performance wise you won't get much by refactoring.

Since you are not doing any logical operations (like increasing/decreasing etc..) after receiving, it's okay to invoke getter multiple times. After all there is a variable that you are getting which is returning by that method.

Unless you are doing some costly operations inside your getter, your code looks ok to me.

Note that, if you are in multi threaded environment, it's ways better to use the getter, since there are chances of modifications of the variable you are getting.

Comment: For multi-threading, I wouldn't say it's *always* better to avoid storing a getter's result in a variable - it depends on context. For the example in the question, that could lead to executing *none* of the if statements (or multiple of them, if we're not using else-if), where you may instead want to always execute exactly one for each function call.

Comment: @Dukeling Well. Agree with you. Again a catch22 :)

Comment: @Dukeling huh? You may get the inconsistent results if you do *not* store the value into a local variable, as then, each `getAge()` invocation may return a different result. So it’s obviously better to *store* the value into a variable, not to avoid it.

Comment: @Holger You may have misread my comment - that's what I was saying.

Comment: @Dukeling I see, “wouldn't say it's always better to avoid” exceeded my parsing capabilities. And I would say, there is *never* a reason to avoid a local variable. Calling the same method multiple times is code duplication, even if the code is small. Well, even if the method is called only once, if the developers feels like storing the result in a local variable first, before using it, there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Can we say that one approach is better than other?
I'd say to go with new variable as if you need to change the method you wanted to access, for example user.getYearOfBirth() instead of user.getAge(), you'd need to change a lot of parts in your code instead of just one time if you assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

its helps with speed. its only has to process the statement once instead of everytime.

Comment: It also creates a prime opportunity to introduce a logic error because now you have a duplicate of a value in an object.